# Installation of roots doesn't work

Tags: node.js, roots-toolkit

I'm trying to install [roots](http://roots.cx/) but it's not working. I'm running the command mentioned on the website:

```
curl roots.cx/get | sh
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
\e[31m✘\e[0m \e[1mlooks like you need to install or update node.js.\e[0m
```

I do have node.js installed (v 0.8.16) and it can be run from the command line.

Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: What does your `$PATH` look like? What system are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.1O, node.js is in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the install script is broken. You can just install roots via npm:

```
npm install roots -g
```